# Getting an error when running ExecuteNonQuery() using sybase AseCommand

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-web-api, ado.net, sybase

I am getting an error when I run the writetext sql command in C# ADO.NET using the sybase provider Sybase.AdoNet4.AseClient.  I have tried a lot of different things, e.g using parameterindex, named parameters, etc.  Can someone please help?  I am showing sample code below.

```
AseConnection cn = new AseConnection(connection.ConnectionString);
cn.Open();

//..... there is other code here that calls a stored procedure and gets textpointer 
// reference, but I am leaving it out to keep it short and simple

AseCommand cmd2 = new AseCommand("writetext mytable.column1 @textPointer @bigText", cn);
cmd2.CommandType = CommandType.Text

cmd2.Parameters.Add(new AseParameter("@textPointer", AseDbType.VarBinary, 16));
cmd2.Parameters["textPointer"].value = textPointerOut.value

cmd2.Parameters.Add(new AseParameter("@bigText", AseDbType.Text));
cmd2.Parameters["bigText"].value = bigText;

cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

cmd2.ExecuteNoQuery() throws an exception and the error is **Must declare variable @textPointer**

Update: If I try this syntax below, I get an error saying **Incorrect sntax near '@bigText'**

```
AseCommand cmd2 = new AseCommand("{writetext mytable.column1 @textPointer @bigText}", cn);
```

Comment: I didn't work with Sybase and Asecommand…,but, you may not need to use @ when setting values to parameters.

Comment: @isaeid I will try your suggestion.  Thanks.

Comment: @isaeid Made the change as per your suggestion.  I am still getting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

I got too stuck with passing a AseParameter to the dynamic SQL.  No need to use a named parameter.  Using dynamic sql, I had to do the following:

1. Declare textPointer variable
2. Get the pointer to the column I want to update
3. Update column by using the the writetext command